# Getting alert empty from php code ?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I not know why in following js code alert is empty without html code, my view have html code, and my_class work true for other controller, when i get alert this means it is work true js code but get data of php code without html. what do i do?

```
function guide_show($offset = 0) {
$find = $this -> input -> post('find');
$where = "name LIKE '%$find%' OR phone LIKE '%$find%' OR mobile LIKE '%$find%' OR address LIKE '%$find%' OR date_submit LIKE '%$find%' OR useradmin_submit LIKE '%$find%'";
$table = "guide";
$url_pag = "admin/submits/guide_show";
$order = "id";
$data = $this -> my_class -> show($where, $table, $url_pag, $order, $offset);
    $this->load->view('admin/guide_show', $data);
}
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    url: url,
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        alert(html)
    },
    "error": function (x, y, z) {
        // callback to run if an error occurs
        alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
    }
})
```

Here is My_class(library): http://pastebin.com/6DxjmBFC

Here is my htm code in view(guide_show): http://pastebin.com/mtubjzvB

Comment: I suggest you using [Firefox](http://www.firefox.com) + [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/httpfox/) to analyse your HTTP request.

Comment: Have you already watched the HTTP requests? In Firefox you could use Firebug. Other browsers have build in developer tools to watch the HTTP requests.

Comment: @AliciaCibrian, use Developer Tools in Chrome. Shortcut key: Ctrl+Shift+I

Answer (score 0):

Check on Firebuq ->  NET [ Expand ] and show response body